# Get max ID value in PowerShell 5.1 DataTable

Tags: powershell

I'm using `Invoke-SqlCmd` to get a `DataTable` result. Is there a way to get the **max value** of the ID column in the DataTable in PowerShell?

```
$sqlResult = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query 'select * from customer' -ServerInstance '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB' -Database 'Database1' -OutputAs DataTables
$sqlResult.GetType()
$sqlResult | Out-Host
```

[image]

Comment: Without looking at your output, you could use the `.` operator to reference the property and then pipe to `Measure-Object -Max`

Comment: Measure-Object : Cannot compare "System.Data.DataRow" because it is not IComparable.

Comment: `($sqlResult.Id | Measure-Object -Max).Max` is what Abraham pointed out above, your error implies you haven't referenced the `Id` property of your `DataTable`

Comment: If you add this answer, I'll mark it as answer. Do you know how I can find more information on how I can act on DataTable object?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon where can I get more info on what I can do on a DataTable in PowerShell. I can seem to google correct words

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your question, [`DataTable` is a .NET class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0) everything you can do with it is on the .NET docs, not matter the language (pwsh, c#, VB...)